# discord.py (rewrite) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord.py

I'm trying to add a background discord.py task using discord.ext.tasks.
This task is supposed to rename a voice channel to the bot's ping every so often.
Here is the code:

```py
    @tasks.loop(seconds=1.0)
    async def ping_display(self):
        ch = None
        chs = self.client.get_all_channels()
        for chan in chs:
            if chan.id == display:
                ch = chan

        await ch.edit(name=f'Ping - {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/blah/blah/blah/blah/cogs/background_tasks.py", line 29, in ping_display
    await ch.edit(name=f'Ping - {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

For context, `display` is the 'display' channel's ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few months ago, I had the same error, and usually, that's because the loop calls when the program's run, even when the client doesn't have a connection to discord.py. To solve this, you can add the following code after the task:

```
@ping_display.before_loop
async def before_ping_display(self):
    await self.client.wait_until_ready()
```

this makes it so that the task will wait until your program has established a connection, then it will run.

Another possible case is that you haven't found the channel in `self.client.get_all_channels`. You can also get a specific channel by doing:

```
guild = self.client.get_guild(guild_id)
ch = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, and sorry for the late response! I've tried this code out and it worked perfectly. Thanks!